# Can 2s2p battery be checked with 2s bms?

Tags: arduino, lithium-ion, charger, bms

I decided to make a 2s2p rechargeable battery to power the Arduino.  I am not sure if this setup can work, and i have no idea what kind of charging module to use.

[image: my schema]